# Is leq sufficient for the existence of a slack variable based bfs in a simplex?

Tags: linear-programming

I'm attempting to write a MPS to custom format converter for a generalized simplex algorithm and I am running into a couple of difficulties.

According to [this tutorial](http://businessmanagementcourses.org/Lesson09TheBigMMethod.pdf) on the Big-M method for finding a basic feasible solution the following is necessary for an alternative approach, an all slack solution.

> In my examples so far, I have looked 
>   at problems that, when put into standard LP form, conveniently have an all slack 
>   starting solution. An all slack solution is only a possibility when all of the 
>   constraints in the problem have <= inequalities.

Granted this url identifies itself as a business course so the level of rigor may not be great. In any case the language it uses is that it is necessary. First off, I am wondering if this is true.

However it will be even more useful for me if it is sufficient. I don't need it to be necessary. Is it known whether sufficiency is true for this condition?

Comment: Use your intuition: adding one slack variable to each $\le$ constraint implies that your initial basis will be the identity matrix. Hence, if all your constraints are of this type you will always have a BFS. But it is not necessary, as the trivial example $\max{x_1+x_2}$ s.t. $x_1 \le 3, x_2 \le 5$ shows.

Comment: Hence if I am using a non-standard form (introducing negative RHS) I can easily convert $x\geq b$ and $x=b$ into one or more $x'\leq b'$ and side step the trouble of Big-M. Thank you!

Comment: Most of the modern simplex implementations use the Two-phase approach, where Phase 1 solves a smaller LP to create an initial bfs which is then passed to Phase II. You could check out that paradigm as well.